# Why was WorkflowPipelineArgs Comments changed to CommentFields in Sitecore 8?

Tags: workflow

Previously we used `string WorkflowPipelineArgs.Comments` which seems got obsolete now and suggests to use `StringDictionary WorkflowPipelineArgs.CommentFields`.

By using Reflector tool I found that to read comments I should write as below:

`WorkflowPipelineArgs.CommentsField["Comments"]`

My question is why it was changed like that and what other values we can find from `CommentFields` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find any new fields there out of the box. But Sitecore recently introduced the `Standard Comment Template`, thereby making it possible to cook up more advanced authoring scenarios.

[image]

Grant Bartlett has a good example of what that could look like in [Sitecore 8: Advanced workflow commenting](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/04/Sitecore-8-Advanced-Workflow-Commenting.aspx)

In short; it was changed because Sitecore now has the ability to attach a "Comment Template" to workflows, and therefore it is now easier to extend for specific needs.